# sharepoint 2010 user profiles Access denied error

Tags: 2010, permissions, my-site, user-profile-service, access-denied

We have provisioned MySites for users and created a new permission level according to our company requirements, wherein the Mysite is visible only to the MySite owners. Now, from whichever page we are in the application when we click on the name of a user of the application, it takes us to their profile page. However, now we notice that, for all those users for whom MySite is provisioned, it shows an "Access Denied" error. I am new to SharePoint and don't know if this is because of the permissions of MySite.

What I want to implement is that MySites should be accessible only to the owners of the MySite but everyone's profile page must be visible to everyone else. Any help on this will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: usually MySites only available to the Owner & Manager. Could you please share the what option you selected for permission level?

Comment: we created a custom permission level, where site permissions included that users could view pages, browse user information and edit personal information. But we are not able to see the user profile of users with Mysites when we click on their name from other pages in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I would begin by removing your "special permissions" and then re-test. It is very likely that your change is causing the issue. Next, to help us in troubleshooting, you need to clarify the difference between the "My Site Host" and "Personal Site".

**My Site Host** - Contains pages that should always be "Public". This is where the user profile is viewed (Person.aspx), the Newsfeed is viewed, and user profile photos are stored. (If you secure the user photos you will have issues.) Permissions for the My Site Host are controlled in the User Profile Service Application Settings.

**Personal Site** - This is the site collection for each user where they store documents (their OneDrive for Business), create lists and sub-sites. The user is the Owner of the Site Collection. This site also stores the users Social Feeds, if you delete, change permissions or interfere with any of these lists, you will cause problems for the My Site Host.

Understanding these differences and how the separate site collections interact is VITAL before you attempt to make any changes to either the My Site Host or to the Personal Sites. For example, are you publishing something to the profile from the Personal Site that should be private to the user? This will cause access denied.